# Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

Tags: npm, babeljs, babelify

So far I have been unsuccessful in an attempt to use the `env` preset. I browsed the git issues that others have raised such as [this](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/186), and implemented some of the suggestions that appeared to work for others, but no luck so far.

Here's what I'm working with:

package.json

```
"bundle": "browserify ./client/app.js -d -o ./public/o.js -t [ babelify --presets [ env ] ]",
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babelify": "^8.0.0"
...
```

And here is the error:

```
Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/Users/user/Documents/git/ts/client" while parsing file: /Users/user/Documents/git/ts/client/app.js
```

Anything I could be missing?

Answer (score 37):

Many of the github issues relating to this suggest that `babel-preset-env` is not installed.

Indeed it doesn't seem to be there in your `package.json`.  Add & install it by doing this:

`npm install babel-preset-env --save`

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue actually was but the preset-env is installed. I did not, however, have `@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40` installed. After installing that and using babel (instead of babelify), it started working.

Answer (score 9):

Though the earlier answers do provide the right solution and it works. But this should be installed as a dev dependency not as the core one. As this is needed only for development work. If you are **using npm you can use:**

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env`

or if you are using **yarn as package manager then use:**

`yarn add --dev babel-preset-env`

Answer (score 5):

You just need to install `babel-preset-env` and your code will compile properly.

`npm install babel-preset-env`

Comment: Just making the reply more specific: `npm install babel-preset-env`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this type of error occurs due to mismatch in versions of babel-core, babel-preset-env and babel-loader. Below are matched and tested `devDependencies`, which worked for me.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether `.babelrc` file exists in the directory above or above the directory. Just delete the file is OK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).