# Couldn't find preset "@babel/preset-env"

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

please can anyone help me?
I have this package:
https://github.com/xbrain-dev/xbrain-validate

When I install it in a react-native project the following error happens:

> /Users/diegovieira/Sites/ConexaoClaroBrasilMobile/node_modules/xbrain-validate/dist/xbrain-validate.min.js: Couldn't find preset "@babel/preset-env" relative to directory "/Users/diegovieira/Sites/ConexaoClaroBrasilMobile/node_modules/xbrain-validate"

Comment: maybe you just have to install it via "npm install babel-preset-env --save"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848249/couldnt-find-preset-env-relative-to-directory)

Comment: But in the xbrain-validate package the @babel/preset-env package is a dependency of dev, why should I install in the main project?